# Unable to connect to server through cyberpanel and putty and even website is not working

Tags: vps

### I recently moved to hostinger VPS plan and installed ubuntu 20.04 and cyber panel on my server and I was able to issue SSL for my hostname and domain but when I tried issuing SSL for mail server SSL for both hostname and domain were lost and I used Cloudflare services and added DNS records and suddenly everything is lost and I am unable to access cyber panel 8090 URL and my website URL and all the URLs give the same following error

This site can’t be reached185.210.144.230 took too long to respond.
Try:

### Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I had same kind of issue in the past and I had to change the OS and change back to ubuntu setup the server again, I can't keep doing the same every time.
If anyone has gone through the same issue please help me with the resolution.
I am new to this and I am trying to learn to be an expert.
am I doing something wrong with Cloudflare or the server?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it's about the DNS, make sure to set the records correctly then give it a day or two to take affect. Also when you creating a website in CyberPanel don't install SSL(Uncheck the SSL installation during website creation) because SSL won't work if the DNS records didn't set correctly, so first make sure DNS working fine and then install SSL for your website.

If your DNS doesn't work and you keep trying to re-install SSL, below error will occur:

[Let's Encrypt "rate limit"](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).